# Do absentee ballots exist for primary elections?

Tags: united-states, election, new-york

As someone who was born in the US (New York, specifically) but moved out of the country when I was a child, is it possible for me to vote in the primary? (I am still a US citizen)

I already know I am eligible to vote in the main election in November through an absentee ballot. Does a similar system exist for the primaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [New York state Board of Elections](http://www.elections.ny.gov/VotingDeadlines.html), April 12th is the

> Last day to postmark an application or letter of application by mail for an absentee ballot

for the presidential primary. From this, I surmise that you can in fact vote by absentee ballot if you will be absent from the state on primary day.

Answer (score 2):

In most states, absentee ballots are available for all elections. The [New York Absentee Ballot Elections page](http://www.elections.ny.gov/VotingAbsentee.html) makes no specification as to primary or general election, implying that primary balloting is possible by absentee.

The rules for New York are somewhat arcane, so I would visit and read the instructions carefully.